# Hacer login automaticamente Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, login

estoy creando una aplicacion que a la primera vez que se habre la aplicacion en un telefono el usuario tiene que hacer **login**. Pero quisiera que a la segunda vez que ingrese el usuario a la aplicacion, luego de hacer **login** por primera vez, que entre automaticamente a la `activity principal` de la aplicacion y que el usuario no tenga que volver hacer **login**.
No se exactamente como hacer esta operacion, y como guardar los datos de ingreso para no repetir la operacion de **login**. Solamente necesito una idea base para poder empezar con este codigo.
 Muchas gracias a los contestadores.

Comment: Puedes usar las SharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) para guardar el usuario y pass la primera vez que te loguees y la próxima vez comprobar si existen o no, si existen avanzas a la siguiente actividad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea por primera ves los datos de inicio de session a la hora te validar el ingreso

```
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("datosUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("name",TUEDITEXT.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
```

Y en el proximo verifica si existen esos datos

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getApplicationContext()).getSharedPreferences("datosUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Nombre = sharedPreferences.getString("name","PorDefecto");
```